# How should I have written this 'closed as not constructive' question to get suitable answers?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question, [For a web-application, should I programmatically create the database tables or provide a schema file and instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15627214/331024) was closed as 'not constructive'.

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific
>   expertise...

Which is exactly what I was seeking!

> ...but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling,
>   or extended discussion.

Is there a nugget of a good question in there? How should I have written it to get suitable answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems more of a whiteboardy design question to me - I migrated it to [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).